# truffle & solidity cant access to a function in test

Tags: javascript, solidity, truffle

after I run command truffle test
I got this error

> TypeError: _character.getName is not a function

my test file

```
let Game = artifacts.require("./Game.sol");
let Character = artifacts.require("./Character.sol");

const PROVIDED_NAME = "TEST";

contract("Game", (accounts) => {

    let creatorAccount = accounts[0];

    it("should create a character with the name provided", () => {
        let _game;
        let _character;

        return Game.deployed()
            .then(instance => {
                _game = instance;
                return _game.createCharacter(PROVIDED_NAME, { from: creatorAccount });
            })
            .then(result => {
                return _game.getCharacter();
            })
            .then(character => {
                _character = Character.at(character);
                return _character.getName();
            })
            .then(name => {
                assert.equal(name, PROVIDED_NAME, "Failed to create a character with the provided name");
            });
    });
});
```

and this my Character.sol file

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.15;

contract Character {
    string private _name;

    constructor(string memory name) public {
        _name = name;
    }

    function getName() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }
}
```

I'm using

> Truffle v5.5.20 (core: 5.5.20)
> Ganache v7.2.0
> Solidity - 0.8.15 (solc-js)
> Node v16.15.1
> Web3.js v1.7.4

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the way how you require them. you should not pass the directory path, instead pass the name of the contracts, truffle will assign them.

```
let Game = artifacts.require("NameOfGamecontract");
let Character = artifacts.require("NameOfCharacterContract");
```